# Limit access to specific database only, and restrict access to system tables

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I have a user `test`, which can view data from the system tables such as `pg_class`. The idea is to isolate him to have access to a specific database only 
and not have any access to system resources.

I don't want him having access to tables like `pg_stat_replication`, `pg_stat_activity`, or using any of the functions like `pg_current_xlog_location();`.

The question is, how can one achieve this?

For example:

```
Create user test with password test
```

I cannot create DB or create another user or role, however I have access to let's say `pg_class` (by default, even the path is not set to public it is set to test schema), which I actually would like to prevent in general.

In Oracle (where I come from), there is the principle of least privilege in other words you create a user and it does not have any privilege or role granted to him.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this goal by revoking certain privileges.  You might have the reasons to do so - the only scenario where I'd start thinking about it is multi-tenancy.  Still, in this case, it is better not to allow the tenants to directly touch the database.

So, after this detour, what do you have to revoke?  For functions it's the `EXECUTE` privilege, for tables and views `SELECT` - ordinary users cannot change data in `pg_catalog` anyway.  For cleanliness, it is possibly better to revoke `ALL`, which then includes the former two as applicable.

Let's see now what happens:

```
# CREATE USER lame_bob [WITH PASSWORD 'l'];  -- note that this way the password 
                                             -- might appear in the database logs, 
                                             -- so use psql's \password command instead

# REVOKE EXECUTE ON FUNCTION pg_current_xlog_location() FROM lame_bob;

# \c test lame_bob

> SELECT pg_current_xlog_location();

 pg_current_xlog_location 
──────────────────────────
 0/26517910
```

Oops.

The trick here is the `public` pseudorole, which has privileges on certain objects (like `EXECUTE` on the function in this example).  To disable Lame Bob, this has to be also revoked:

```
> \c test dezso

# REVOKE EXECUTE ON FUNCTION pg_current_xlog_location() FROM public;

# \c test lame_bob

> SELECT pg_current_xlog_location();

ERROR:  permission denied for function pg_current_xlog_location
```

In turn, this might disable other users, too, who should keep the ability of using this function.  If necessary, you can grant them the `EXECUTE` privilege one by one - but there is a better way:

```
# CREATE ROLE can_use_system_functions; -- no login rights

# GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION pg_current_xlog_location() TO can_use_system_functions;

# GRANT can_use_system_functions TO able_alice;
```

And then `able_alice` (and all other users that eventually gets the membership in `can_use_system_functions`) will be able to do what they need to do.  Allowing new users to these objects is just a matter of granting them this single umbrella role.